# AWT text measuring implementations

Tags: java, optimization, awt

The Java 6 (J2SE) implementation of `AttributedString`, `TextLayout`, and `LineBreakMeasurer` classes use anti-aliasing properties and fractional math for metrics calculations. This causes a severe performance penalty.

What suggestions (for Cent OS Linux) do you have to increase performance? Such as:

- A faster JVM (JDK 1.7, Oracle's JRockit, IBM)
- A different AWT implementation (any?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the [`java.awt.FontMetrics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) class give any better performance? It may still be used by the classes you've mentioned, but it's a pre-Java 6 implementation at least.

Comment: The code that uses those three classes is rather complex; someone is else working on the problem; if they can use a single class, I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: This is probably the only viable alternative, whether it works or not. Thank you.